# ReactJS - MappleToolTip not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I followed the installation instructions on https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-mappletooltip

Nothing from the MappleToolTip renders or even shows up in the page source when I inspect the page source in Chrome. What am I doing wrong? I tried to include as a separate component as well with same results, nothing from MappleToolTip rendering.

My Code:
(NOTE: code has been shortened for readability)

ToolTip.js

```
import React from 'react';

var MappleToolTip = require('reactjs-mappletooltip');

export const PageWithToolTip = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <MappleToolTip>
        <div>
          Show Mapple Tip on this
        </div>
        <div>
          Hey! this is damn easy        
        </div>
      </MappleToolTip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

FoodMenu.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {PageWithToolTip} from './ToolTip';

class FoodMenu extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="section-meals">
        <div className="row">
          <h2>
            - Menu -
          </h2>
        </div>
        {PageWithToolTip}
      </div>
     )
   }
}

export default FoodMenu;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `<PageWithToolTip/>` instead of `{PageWithToolTip}`.

And change import to `import MappleToolTip from 'reactjs-mappletooltip';`

Comment: When I do that, I get this error React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check your code at ToolTip.js:8.

Comment: Have you tried `import MappleToolTip from 'reactjs-mappletooltip';` ?

Comment: That works! Thank you Andrew! Can you change your answer to reflect this? I'll mark it as the answer!

Comment: Glad to help:)
If it was helpful, you can accept my answer.

Comment: Can you change your answer to reflect this? I'll mark it as the answer! Thank you Andrew!

Comment: To get it working, I did the import MappleToolTip and called the <MappleToolTip><div>text</div><div>text</div></MappleToolTip> in the render method. The PageWithToolTip did not work so I just deleted PageWithToolTip and its corresponding ToolTip.js file